# Circe Decoding "AnyContentAsJson" type in Scala Play

Tags: scala, playframework, circe

I am trying to parse the body of an incoming request to JSON using Circe and Scala Play.  The incoming request is coming from Postman as I'm running the service locally for testing purposes.

The decode I am using is: `decode[LoginRequest](request.body.toString)`

Whenever I run this, though, Circe throws an error because it receives "unexpected JSON", which is the JSON I'm expecting but wrapped in this object `AnyContentAsJson`

Anyone know how I can fix this?  Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using as well as the request body you are sending?

Answer (score 1):

I changed my line of code to `decode[LoginRequest](request.body.asJson.get.toString)`

The Play Actions (aka my `Action.async`) parses the JSON Body based on the Content-Type header.  Because I am sending a JSON Body, it returns the AnyContentAsJson object.  From there, you can use the `as` methods to parse and then decode.

Information found here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaBodyParsers